# What makes a structured set a set of numbers?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, foundations

I wonder which characteristics of a (structured) set $X$  let us consider it a set of numbers.

Does the existence of two operations $+: X \times X \rightarrow X$ and $\times: X \times X \rightarrow X$ suffice which obey some laws, e.g. the laws of a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_theory)? So would we consider each and every ring a set of "numbers"? Or has there to be more? Which structured sets are far from being a ring but considered a set of numbers nevertheless?

For example, the set of natural numbers doesn't form a ring, but is considered a set of numbers. And the set of prime numbers doesn't form a ring, but is considered a set of numbers. So maybe being a subset of a ring does suffice? But each and every subset? What are the minimal requirements?

Note, that there are different kinds of numbers:

- counting (cardinal) numbers
- ordering (ordinal) numbers
- relating (rational) numbers
- constructible (algebraic) numbers
- measuring (real) numbers

Some kinds of numbers don't fit into this scheme, e.g. [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), complex numbers or [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions), or do they?

What do these kinds of numbers have in common?

---

[This question has to do with the question [What is (a) geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192055/what-is-a-geometry) which may be rephrased: What makes a (structured) set a set of **points**?]

Comment: Numbers are usually thought of as "scalars" (= one-dimensional entities). If you allow complex numbers (= two-dimensional entities) as numbers, why shouldn't you quaternions (= four-dimensional entities)?

Comment: The other way around: Why do people consider complex numbers as numbers, but not so likely quaternions? What's the difference between the two? Is it just a matter of acquaintance?

Answer (score 1):

There was a time when each of $-1, 0, $ and $1$ were not considered numbers.

The modern use of structures, $\{[\mathbf S, +, \times] + \text{axioms}\}$, for example, allows us to abstract away nonessential details and create useful theorems. Structures give names to a thing, but they are more concerned with proving theorems about that thing.

[Feynman on the difference between knowing a thing and knowing about a thing](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=feynman%2C%20the%20name%20of%20a%20bird&&view=detail&mid=0E5D04421066C90085400E5D04421066C9008540&rvsmid=5253E443B149510BBCD95253E443B149510BBCD9&FORM=VDQVAP)

I think that, because of mathematical structures, the exact definition of number will always be a fuzzy and controversial thing. I don't plan on losing any sleep over that.

Comment: +1: Cool answer: "I don't plan on losing any sleep over that." Neither do I. But even without losing any sleep, one might be able to give an answer?

Comment: @HansStricker - How can we define what a number is when we still argue over whether or not $0$ is a natural number.