# Is there a geometry where the distance between two points can be complex?

Tags: geometry

This [tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/andyweirauthor/status/1246472992491630592) contained this image which is of course complete nonsense but it got me thinking -- is there such a thing where the distance of two points is a complex number?

[image]

Ps. it seems such questions are fit for this SE for example [Can there be a geometry where angles can be infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3496618/6400)

Comment: If by "distance" you mean metric, then no: a metric is by definition real valued

Answer (score 5):

Akbar Azam, Brian Fisher & M. Khan (2011) Common Fixed Point Theorems in Complex Valued Metric Spaces, Numerical Functional Analysis and Optimization, 32:3, 243-253, DOI: [10.1080/01630563.2011.533046](https://doi.org/10.1080/01630563.2011.533046)

> We introduce complex valued metric spaces and obtain sufficient conditions for the existence of common fixed points of a pair of mappings satisfying contractive type conditions.

While I can't find this paper freely available online, this [PDF](http://www.bomsr.com/BOMSR%201.1/KPR%201-8%20mod.pdf) cites it and defines " XxX→C is called a complex valued b-metric":

[image]

Comment: Fair enough, I deleted my comment. That's the trouble with words, you get these "eats shoots and leaves" problems.

Answer (score 1):

There can be no such metric, as it would not obey the requirements of a metric.  Specifically, you must be able to have the "$>$" operation (for the triangle inequality: $d(a,b) + d(b,c) \geq d(a,c)$), and that does not hold for complex numbers.

Comment: -1: the question doesn't even contain the word "metric". And you could apply your answer to the word "measure", yet complex and even operator-valued measures are a thing (and a useful one!).

Comment: @MartinArgerami:  "distance" implies the *metric*, for instance "Euclidean distance" is a direct result of a "Euclidean metric."  Any distance must obey the rules of a metric:  $d(x,x) = 0$, $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$, and $d(x,y) + d(y,z) \geq d(x,z)$.  Look it up.

Comment: @MartinArgerami is there a complex valued measure on the one dimensional Euclidean space ?

Comment: Yes, lots.$\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

A distance is always a real number, for reasons given in other answers. It is only when the angle is also introduced to make it a vector that things get complex. For example the shortest *distance* from one point to another is a real number, but the shortest *path* is a vector and may prove to be complex.